# How to make an ad wrapper which displays a message if a user has adblock running?

Tags: html, css, background-image, adblock

I have a website with an ad on every page.

I'd like to display a message saying, "Please consider disabling your adblock, it helps us out tremendously." if the user has AdBlock enabled.

Here's my attempt:

```
<div id="ad-wrapper">
    <!-- Ad script here. It works fine. -->
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
#ad-wrapper {
    background-color: #1D1D1D;
    border: 1px solid #232323;
    float: right;
    height: 90px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    width: 728px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-image: url('/Public/images/disabled-ad.jpg');
}
```

When I turn off AdBlock the ad is displayed correctly without issues.

When I turn it on, AdBlock completely makes the `#ad-wrapper` invisible. I thought it would only remove the ad, leaving my background-image message there for my users to see.

How can I accomplish this behavior?

Comment: Chances are that anyone blocking your advert will also want to block your message...

Comment: @Neil: You don't disable adblock on sites you support?

Comment: I don't install AdBlock... occasionally I use homebrew methods of blocking ads, but only if they are really annoying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume Ad Block is blocking your wrapper because it contains the word "ad". Try using something like:

```
<div id="disabled-wrapper">
    <!-- Ad script here. It works fine. -->
</div>
```